# JQuery addClass / hasClass with repeating button elements

Tags: jquery, css, button, addclass

I'm still very new to Jquery / Javascript so I'm struggling to understand how to implement the following.

Basically I use the same button class site wide and i'm trying to get Jquery to serve up a "clicked" class to only the button that was clicked and not the others.

This is what I've got...

```
$(".button-img").click(function()  {
    var clickedButton = $(this);
    if clickedButton.hasClass('clicked') {
        return false;
    }
    clickedButton.addClass('clicked');
});
```

And what I'm trying to do is better explained in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/biggee/FQqL8/1/

I know what i'm doing is wrong, although I think I'm on the right lines, but after reading a whole bunch of tutorials i'm still just not getting it. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: But you don't need to check, the `addClass()` method won't add a duplicate class-name to an element anyway. If the class to add is already present jQuery/`addClass()` will simply skip straight on by, doing nothing (other than checking whether it's there or not).

Comment: Ahh so I can drop all the has Class / return false stuff then?

Comment: Absolutely! And it's much easier (to write, and read) that way. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you had a parse error in your code:

```
if clickedButton.hasClass('clicked') {
```

Is missing the required parentheses:

```
if (clickedButton.hasClass('clicked')) {
```

Second, your CSS is wrong too:

```
.button-img .clicked {
    background-position:0px -60px;
}
```

That matches an element with class `clicked` *inside* `.button-img`; what you probably meant was this:

```
.button-img.clicked {
    background-position:0px -60px;
}
```

This matches the `.button-img` element if it also has the `clicked` class.

Lastly, to make your code even easier:

```
$(".button-img").on('click', function() {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, most appreciated

Comment: How could I disable each button after it's clicked? Also, would it be better to control the hover action via Jquery rather than css and if so how would I set that up?

Comment: What do you mean by disabled? Don't do hover with jQuery btw, CSS is well equipped for it.

Comment: I mean disable the CSS hover. Once the class is changed to "clicked" the hover element still works at the moment.

Comment: Doh... The old brain isn't working tonight.. Fixed, just added a new hover class for clicked. Sorry. That was a proper noob one ;)

Comment: @Grant Yeah, another class would the approach I would take :)

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/FQqL8/5/)***

Remember to always check the console for errors.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

You are missing parenthesis here:

```
if clickedButton.hasClass('clicked') {
```

Should be

```
if (clickedButton.hasClass('clicked')) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Doh!

Answered my own question..

I had the css class set up wrong from an earlier way of trying it..

Before...

```
.button-img .clicked {background-position:0px -60px;}
```

Now... (and working)

```
.clicked {background-position:0px -60px;}
```

Thanks guys ;)

Comment: That will match *any* element that has `clicked` class; I wouldn't recommend this approach for such a generic class name.

Comment: Totally. I just simplified the class names to make it easier to read, the actual classes are very specific.